# How to create a download link (PDF) in React

Tags: reactjs

The PDF file is in my local folder. In fact the same folder where my component is:

[image]

I checked few answers on stackoverflow and my code is:

```
...
const Footer = (props) => {
    return (
      <a href="./Tanzeel_Mirza_Resume.pdf" download="Tanzeel_Mirza_Resume.pdf">Download</a>
    )
}
...
```

When I click on this link, the PDF gets downloaded but it is blank and size is also 9kb while the actual PDF is 2MB in size.

Clearly I'm doing some silly mistake here. Please point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing the PDF, then downloading with the link, like so:

```
import pdf from "./Tanzeel_Mirza_Resume.pdf"

const Footer = (props) => {
return (
  <a href={pdf}>Download</a>
)
}
```

Also, I wanted to point out that you can avoid the ugly hash appended to the file name with this method by specifying a file name with the download property, like this:

```
<a href={pdf} download="FileName.pdf">Download</a>
```

Comment: Yes, i tired the second approach also i.e. without using `.` but it didnt work. 
But your `import ...` approach worked like charm.

Comment: I actually meant to try it even without the `/` (I edited to reflect this). Either way, glad to hear it's workin for ya!

Comment: yes yes, i tried that way also. Still didnt work :)

Comment: Noted... And removed. Though surprising as I seem to remember using that technique.